# how to get an argument from an outer function? python

Tags: python, function, lambda

I would like to create a function with one string argument. This function should return an anonymous function that checks if the function argument is equal to the argument of the external function. But I do not understand how to get the argument of an external function.

```
def create(arg): 
     outer = 

     return lambda a: outer == arg

firstValue = create("secret")

print(firstValue("secret"))  # >> True

print(firstValue("SECRET"))  # >> False
```

Comment: You just want `def create(arg): return lambda a: a == arg`

Comment: There is no need for `outer`, I'm pretty sure you just mean the argument to the lambda, i e. `a`... Your use of "outer function" terminology is confusing here

Comment: A parameter is just a local variable that gets initialized by the function call itself, rather than via an explicit assignment in the body of the function.

Comment: why don't you use the `a` parameter at all?

Comment: You accidentally did the right thing: you used `arg` in the body of the anonymous function. (I suspect you were thinking of `lambda a: outer == a`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create(arg): 
     return lambda a: a == arg # replace outer with a

firstValue = create("secret")

print(firstValue("secret"))  # >> True

print(firstValue("SECRET"))  # >> False
```

**Edit: (for explanation)**

The first function, `create("secret")`, takes as argument `arg = "secret"`.
Following the execution of its body, it creates the other lambda function that takes as argument `a` and compares it to `"secret"`; that function is returned. Again, remember that the function that is being returned is a function that takes one parameter `a` and compares it to the value `"secret"`; it's as if you just did manually this:

```
def anonymous(a):
   return a == "secret"
```

That's the function that is returned.
Now you are assigning this returned function to the name `firstValue`; it's as if you are doing this: `firstValue = anonymous`.

Finally you are just calling THIS function with argument `a="secret"` or `a="SECRET"`, which obviously returns `True` in the first case and `False` in the second.

Comment: Thank you) it works but i just don't understand why it works that way

Comment: @self look for the explanation in the edits of the answer :)